# Initializing a char * with an expression does not work

Tags: c++, string, pointers, temporary-objects

The following code is producing the incorrect output:

```
string my_string="My_First_Text";
char * my_pointer=(char *)(my_string+"My_Second_Text").c_str();
```

Why? As I am initializing `my_pointer`, I presumed that no `my_pointer=new char[100]` is needed. If this assumption is not true, then why?

Comment: Thou shalt heed thy warnings. Oh, I see, you cast the warning away: You are on your own now, and that's Not A Good Thing as it seems.

Comment: As an aside, the code does not produce any output, much less any incorrect.

Comment: [This is what the compiler told you](http://ideone.com/hWe8mu).  But for some reason, you thought you knew better than the compiler and casted away the error.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, @Paul: The disabled warning has nothing to do with the problem.  Add `const` to the second line and no more warning, but the problem is still there.

Comment: @Ben You are right. I think all answers point out the temporary problem which is causing the trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `my_string+"My_Second_Text"` is a temporary `std::string`, which will be destroyed after the expression immediately. That means `my_pointer` will become dangled at once, because the char array it's supposed to point to has been destroyed along with the destroy of the temporary `std::string`; note that the returned char array belong to `std::string`, it's not standalone. Then, deference on dangled pointer would lead to UB.

```
string my_string="My_First_Text";
char * my_pointer=(char *)(my_string+"My_Second_Text").c_str();
// the temporary constructed from my_string+"My_Second_Text" has been destroyed
// my_pointer is dangled now; deference on it is UB
```

Using named variable instead of temporary will be fine. e.g.

```
string my_string = "My_First_Text";
my_string += "My_Second_Text";
const char * my_pointer = my_string.c_str();
```

BTW: The return type of [std::basic_string::c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) is `const char*`, and any modification on it is UB. So trying to convert it to `char*` explicitly is dangerous.

> Writing to the character array accessed through `c_str()` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Modifying the storage pointed to by a pointer to const is only UB if the object is indeed const (which a string's char array clearly isn't, since it has been allocated dynamically). C++ 2012 std, 7.1.6.1: `int i=2; const int *cip; cip = &i; int* ip; ip = const_cast<int*>(cip); *ip = 4;`  is fine.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider The case is more complex here, `std::string` is involved. Anyway, [std::basic_string::c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) says the returned array shouldn't be modified. "Writing to the character array accessed through c_str() is undefined behavior."

Comment: True (std 21.4.7.1). But the reason is not the constness ;-).

Comment: @songyuanyao  I totally understood my mistake and now I know how to resolve it in a correct way. But can I also resolve the issue by using `const char * my_pointer` instead of `char* my_pointer`? In the other words, by using `const char * my_pointer` can I force compiler to store the result of `my_string+"My_Second_Text"` somewhere and don't destroy it at the end of `;`?

Comment: @Admia No, because the fact that `my_pointer` will become dangled along with the destroy of temporary `std::string` doesn't change, so it's still UB. (UB means, even it might seem working fine in some situations but you can't rely on it at all. It's just monster in C++ world.)

Answer (score 3):

Apart from casting the `c_str` (`const char*`) to a `char*`, which is not a good idea, "my_pointer" is initialized using a temporary, and is destructed after the expression is evaluated. meaning, just after the last ';' in your code.
This means that my_pointer points to memory that is no longer valid, and will have unexpected results.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has undefined behavior. `+` operator return a new temporary string object that will be destroyed outside of `(my_string+"My_Second_Text").c_str()` expression so any reference to that string will dangle and accessing through them has undefined behavior.

`c_str()` return a const pointer to internal char array of `string`. you can't and must not manipulate `string` through that pointer.

store the result of `(my_string+"My_Second_Text")` in a new variable or use `append` function to append new string to existing string object.

```
std::string new_string = my_string + "My_Second_Text";
const char* char_pointer = new_string.c_str();

my_string.append("My_Second_Text");
const char* char_pointer = my_string.c_str();
```

Answer (score 3):

`(my_string+"My_Second_Text").c_str()` is a temporal value that will be dynamically created and destroyed without being saved in the memory as the program runs.

Pointing to it will lead to an undefined behaviour, since the pointed memory is not defined. Use `strcpy` or variable assignment instead of temporary value for strings assignment into `char *`.

Answer (score 3):

**Temporary objects** can cause obscure problems.

Related excerpt from Bjarne's C++ book:

> ```
> void f(string& s1, string& s2, string& s3)
> {
>   const char∗ cs = (s1+s2).c_str();  // << Code similar to OP's example
>   cout << cs;
>   if (strlen(cs=(s2+s3).c_str())<8 && cs[0]=='a') {
>   // cs used here
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Probably, your first reaction is **‘‘But don’t do that!’’** and I agree.
>   However, such code does get written, so it is worth knowing how it is
>   interpreted.
>
> A temporary string object is created to hold `s1 + s2`. Next,
>   a pointer to a C-style string is extracted from that object. Then – at
>   the end of the expression – the temporary object is deleted. However,
>   the C-style string returned by `c_str()` was allocated as part of the
>   temporary object holding `s1 + s2`, and that storage is not guaranteed to
>   exist after that temporary is destroyed. Consequently, cs points to
>   deallocated storage.
>
> The output operation `cout << cs` might work as
>   expected, but that would be sheer luck. A compiler can detect and warn
>   against many variants of this problem.

As a side note, use appropriate cast in C++ instead of C-style casting. Read

[When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

Comment: You should render "But don't do that!" in bold, big font, italics.

Comment: Don't you need a const cast here?

Comment: yes @Peter, const_cast would be required. Generalized my answer for casting.

Comment: @SauravSahu I set `-W -Wall` option for my `GNU g++` compiler. But the compiler didn't warn me about this mistake.

Comment: Try `-Wcast-qual`.  Checkout the list https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/Warning-Options.html